# Expanding SKShapeNodes with Joint

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode, skphysicsjoint

I have two SKShapeNode nodes that I want to be attached to each other. When I tap to perform an action I want the two nodes to expand their height and upon tapping again I want them to retract. The problem is that the two nodes aren't animating as expected:

Before animation: (unexpanded)
[image]

After animation: (expanded)
[image]

Both nodes are expanding but it appears that one is going under the other. What I would want to happen is that they "push" each other away.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)

    let firstSection = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: size)
    firstSection.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    firstSection.fillColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
    firstSection.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    firstSection.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 400)
    firstSection.name = "section"
    self.addChild(firstSection)




    let secondSection = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: size)
    secondSection.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    secondSection.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    secondSection.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    secondSection.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300)
    secondSection.name = "section"
    self.addChild(secondSection)

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointSpring.jointWithBodyA(firstSection.physicsBody, bodyB: secondSection.physicsBody, anchorA: firstSection.position, anchorB: secondSection.position)

    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set up the physicsWorld for the view.

Comment: I thought there was a default physicsWorld on the scene? If I don't have the joint the objects push each other away as expected but don't contract back due to no joint

Comment: changing the size of a node won't necessarily change it's physicsBody. In your GameViewController if you set skView.showsPhysics=true then you can see this.

Answer (score 0):

Okapi's comment is correct. Changing the path of an SKShapeNode does not change the size of the attached physics body. However changing the scale does.

The solution would be to use

```
SKAction.scaleYTo(endScale, duration: time)
```

Okapi's also correct in that if you'd like to see what's actually happening in your physics simulation you should set the SKViews showsPhysics property to true.

Hope that's helpful.

**EDIT:** I just realized you're using SKShapeNode, not SKSpriteNode. The scaling physics body still applies, but I'm not sure how you're resizing your nodes (scaling/resizing the path?)